# centos - background processes

Tags: linux, centos, sudo

I have a machine where running tcpdump on wifi interface requires sudo privleges.
So if I run a background job like,

```
sudo tcpdump -i wlp8s0 'port 80' &
```

(I know its meaningless to do it as I am not getting any output of it, but lets consider this)

So a background process that is started with a non-root user scope, when I have to kill it, I normally do,

kill %1     ###1 being the background job number

but this says, operation not permitted.

So then I do,

sudo kill %1

but this works as if it has to kill a background job started by root user (which is not the case).

I had to actually get the job's process id and kill it with that.

Any idea as to how to start a job in sudo scope with non-root user and terminate it normally instead of killing it brutally?

Comment: I do not understand why do you write _brutally_. In which way using kill by a normal user differs from by root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
sudo kill "$!"
```

to kill the most recently started background job.

It would be even easier if you had started the job with

```
sudo tcpdump ... & pid="$!"
```

then

```
sudo kill "$pid"
```

would kill the specific job.

The `sudo` process itself runs as you, but it will relay all signals to the child process (`tcpdump` in this case), which means that you will have to have appropriate permissions to signal it to be able to kill it.

From the `sudo` manual (on an Ubuntu system):

> If an I/O logging plugin is configured or if the security policy explicitly requests it, a new  pseudo-terminal (“pty”) is created and a second sudo process is used to relay job control signals between the
>        user's existing pty and the new pty the command is being run in.  This extra process makes it possible to, for example, suspend and resume the command.
>
> [...]
>
> When the command is run as a child of the sudo process, sudo will relay signals it receives to the command.  The SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals are only relayed when the command is being run in a new pty or when the signal was sent by a user process, not the kernel.

Comment: Thanks kusalananda... Any review of how can I do "nohup" with "tcpdump -i eth0 'port 8080'" so that all the packets it captures are logged to a file (continously as its a background running job) and i dont have to dedicate a terminal for it